# Pandas Producing Excel Taking Too Much Time on Network Drive

Tags: python, excel, pandas

```
#***Code is as below***
import pandas as pd
import time
s = time.time()
x = pd.read_excel(r'D:\CuriosityWhy\Python\01_FileLoadTiming\cv.xls') #size is 100 mb
s = time.time()'#enter code hereenter code here`
x.to_excel(r'\\uk\cv.xlsx')
e = time.time()'`enter code here`
print((e-s)/60) #taking 90 min to complete
# same code taking around 7 min If i use local path to produce excel.I had tried Modin but not any improvement
```

Comment: How long does it take you to retrieve the file through the network? In imagine that there is no magic to expect, if the network/file size are bottlenecks, you won't be able to improve much by trying to tweak software options...

Comment: not sure how many times this experiment was run based on the 90 minutes you said! i would have tried different [engines](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) and also compared with shutil(i.e create the file locally and then copy it to Network drive using `copyfile(src, dst)` ) for curiosity.